# Should we create multiple stories for same thing to be replicated at code level?

Tags: estimation, pivotal-tracker

We have a page with the same content at 2 places. Since we are running with legacy code and due to some previously made bad decisions, we have duplicated the logic twice for the same thing. Both the pages are running on different technologies.

Now if some changes/enhancement come to this, should we create two stories for this OR just one? And should we estimate it considering it would require duplicate effort OR it should be estimated as if its a code at just one common place?

Comment: It’s probably one story with two tasks. Both tasks need to be done per DoD, and that doubled effort should be factored into the story’s estimate.

Comment: Could you see the business being happy to change it in one place and not bother with the other? Would that make sense?

Comment: No.. business wants it at both the places

Answer (score 2):

What you've created is technical debt, and it needs to be refactored.

Do not create duplicate stories, and try not to duplicate code as you just end up paying for things multiple times.  A user story should capture the functionality and business value for a users perspective, if it has to be implemented on both legacy and next gen systems, then you could argue for two, depending on how difficult it is to code/build/test/deploy on the legacy system and whether the user story has to be deployed simultaneously on both.

I recommend having a follow-on task in a subsequent sprint to refactor and clean-up any code duplication that couldn't be done in the existing sprint.

Comment: Yes, I agree that we should fix it asap. But till the time we are maintaining legacy and next-gen system, should we give separate estimations for both?

Comment: Sounds to me like it is separate work implemented in a separate system.  The user story may be the same but the implementation is completely different.  In this case, I would create two separate stories, one marked LEGACY and one tagged NG (next gen) or something similar.  The PO and business should be aware they are paying for something twice and the legacy feature will be retired at some point in the near future.   Emphasize this alot as any dollar spent on legacy is a dollar you can't spend on NG.

Comment: A small disagreement: If you create separate stories for Legacy and New systems, it is the PO's prerogative to de-prioritize or remove one. If they must both be done at the same time and it wouldn't be ok to drop one, I would recommend keeping them together.

Comment: @daniel, if they are dropping one, 'kreping them together' becomes a non issue, lol.

Comment: "legacy and next-gen system" . . . so are they then different products? :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do it in 2 places, I see 2 tasks. Remember that what you estimate and track is the time a task takes, not how much value is got by the client.

And... yes, that duplicity is a problem you have to handle. You are consuming effort that is not translated in value for the client and PO should address it as soon as possible.